# Can I annex fewer certificates for a shorter application?

Tags: university, application, awards

I want to apply at a German university for Computer Science. The instruction tells me to annex documents about additional qualifications.

So I decided for the ten most important and most related qualifications and awards I got and wrote an overview page for them. They are grouped by field and date, and there is a short description of about two lines for every qualification.

Now I need to annex the actual copies of the certificates. I feel uncomfortable with handing in ten copies, plus some other documents. I think providing the certificate for every qualification might result in too much pages which won't get read but make a negative impression.

Can I just provide a few of the copies and tell the University staff to ask for more if wanted?

Comment: is this for graduate or undergraduate studies?

Comment: @Damien I want to apply to a very prestigious German university for an undergraduate program.

Comment: This question _as written_ would also apply to students applying for graduate-level work in Germany, and therefore is on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been my experience that to not include a certified copy of each qualification at least can potentially result in unnecessary delays in processing your application.  Essentially, I have found that many universities frown upon incomplete applications.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder if so many papers could bore the reader. If it would be a job application, I think they just won't read my application or at least not all pages. But do you think this is different for a university application?

Comment: @danijar what I have found now after doing the application 9 times over (I have 9 degrees - undergrad and postgrad), is that they need to have all information for any application.  My experience is for Australia, but I am certain that this necessity is universal, as it is a question of the university having proof of the claims in an application.

Comment: My respect! So I'll send in all copies. Thanks.

Comment: Speaking as someone with experience with the German system, if you claim something, they want to see the certificates.